# Using threading in flask to train a model parallelly

Tags: python, flask, deep-learning, python-multithreading

```
from threading import Thread

def model_training():
    global status
    for i in range(1, 11):
        status = i
        sleep(1)

@app.route('/retrain/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def retrain():
    for th in threading.enumerate():
        if th.name == "training":
            print("Thread still running")
            message = "Training is in already in progress"
            break
    else:
        print("Starting a new job thread")
        message = "Training started"
        t1 = Thread(target=model_training, name="training")
        t1.start()

    return render_template('retrain.html', message=message, models=model_files, num_images=id)
```

I am trying to use threading in flask to train a model in parallel. Above is the sample code of what I am trying to do. With `model_training()` called in thread returns a status as its in a far loop and works fine as expected. But, I would like to train a model by using `model_train()` (below code). In this case it doesn't run in parallel. It waits for the model to complete all epochs.

```
def model_train():
    dataset, model_config, label_mapping = load_config()
    print("Training: start.")

    model = model_config.model

    model.fit()

    print("Training: end.")
```

Can someone guide me to a right direction? Am I missing something here?
Thanks in advance

Comment: does your model.fit() use blocking non-daemon threads ?

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to achieve CPU-bound multithreading, which means trying to improve performance through multithreading.
This is not possible (will not improve performance) in Python default implementation due to the [GIL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1294382/what-is-the-global-interpreter-lock-gil-in-cpython)

However, you can perform multi**processing**, using *multiprocessing* library, or take advantage of your GPU.

Comment: I am not trying to improve the model performance with threading here. I just want to run model when other tasks are performed in parallel. In this case, it would just go to return statement while model is still running.